# What does "I'm not over it" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I was reading a novel and found that in the situation when A had a phone call,
B was standing next to him and asking him repeatedly, "Is it C?", A tried to
wave B off, but B said

> **"I'm not over it."**

and kept bothering A.

I wonder what does the phrase **"I'm not over it"** mean? Thanks.

FYI, here's the excerpt from the fiction:

> Tony fumbles opening the phone. "Hello?"
>
> The person on the other end clears their throat. "Is this Tony Stark?"
>
> "Yeah," Tony answers, then swallows. He tries to shoo Peter away, but
>   the kid doesn't take the hint so he stands up instead.
>
> "Tony?"
>
> "Steve?" Tony replies. He sounds like an idiot.
>
> "That's him?" Peter calls. "I'm not over it."
>
> Tony waves Peter off but there's only silence on the other end of the
>   line.

Comment: It's probably better to include an excerpt of the novel that's related to that particular scene in the question. I think the meaning will become quite clear if we know what A meant by "it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the definition of "over it" as follows:

1) The expression of a loss of interest in something or someone. (e.g., I thought that Bud Light was great beer when I started drinking, but now I'm over it.)

2) The indication that a negative event is no longer bothersome to someone. (e.g., I suffered for days after she broke up with me, but I'm over it now.)

In that context, it could be that B is still not finished with asking A and figuring out if the person who A is on the phone with is C or not. B still wants to know if it is C. Or it might be that there was some event (probably something unpleasant) that happened between B and C which A also knows about before this phone call, and B still has a problem with that event. I don't know the story, so I'm just assuming though...

Comment: I guess the first case makes more sense in my situation.
Can I take that as "if you don't tell me if it is C, i will keep bothering you"?

Comment: Since you're telling me the first case seems to make more sense, yes. If that's the case, that's how I would take it.

Answer (score 2):

In you passage

> I'm not over it.

has the possible meaning that *something* is still bothering the speaker and possibly blocking or holding back his progression through life, possibly something unresolved.

Sometimes in such a situation a friend may say

> I know it's tough, but you've got to get over it.
>   *you need to let go and continue your life*